# Outlook app in windows not showing shared calendar in app, works in web version when we click "show shared Calendar"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Here is the case

Brett has shared his calendar with Amanda who is his VA.

Brett@abc.com (Brett's email) Info@abc.com (Amanda has configured this email)

Now when we are looking at Shared cal on the web there is an option on the left side bottom to say show "Shared Calendar" and it will show all events relating to Brett when we click on radio button next to brett shared cal.

However, In outlook app on windows computers, we have configured info@abc.com as an account and it does show its own calender without issues however we also want to show info about brett's shared calendar in the same calendar just like it shows on web.

Basically, we want info@abc.com to have its own calendar and events but also want to show brett's calender so VA can see and possibly make appointments when needed.

I hope I have been able to explain this clearly. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How did you [shared the calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-an-outlook-calendar-with-other-people-353ed2c1-3ec5-449d-8c73-6931a0adab88)? From calendar permission or something else?

As I know, we can open other's sharing calendar by the following steps:
[image]

Hope the above help!